# Volatility Forensics with Large dumps

Tags: forensics, volatility

Today I was tasked with the analysis of a .vmem file of a Windows RDS one of our customers due to some "strange" connections coming from native Windows processes.

The extracted .vmem file has a size of 20GB.
Requesting the imageinfo with `C:\Python27_64\python.exe vol.py -f XXXXXXX-Snapshot184.vmem imageinfo` has so far taken up to 60 minutes without movement after:

```
Volatility Foundation Volatility Framework 2.6
INFO    : volatility.debug    : Determining profile based on KDBG search...
```

According to the [volatility FAQ](https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility/wiki/FAQ), there have even been reports of memdumps of over 200GB being analyzed with volatility.

What are the best practices to analyze large memdumps?

Granted that patience is a virtue and loading 20GB into memory can take some time, especially if the bytes have to be analyzed for signatures, I am looking for solutions or tips in the trend of:

- File format XXX will give better performance results than format XXX
- Running plugin XXX will speed up usage of future plugins
- Tweaks (unofficial, unsupported, undocumented)

I just can't imagine anyone waiting X days to wait for `imageinfo` to return the correct profile for large dumps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [rekall](http://www.rekall-forensic.com/documentation-1/rekall-documentation/tutorial)?

It is a fork of volatility, while I have had better luck with volatility it might be faster for the initial analysis